# Extracting values frm similar nodesets

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below similar nodesets coming and i want value from each nodeset in a neat manner. If i am giving XPATH, it is taking both as single string and giving like below 203205 and USIND. I want it separated and clear. like 203, 205 or US, IND. Remember the size is dynamic and i cant know the value before hand to make substring and extract. I have to differentiate at node level. Please suggest.

```
<ResultNode>
    <PIN>202</PIN>
    <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
</ResultNode>
<ResultNode>
    <PIN>203</PIN>
    <COUNTRY>IND</COUNTRY>
</ResultNode>
```

Regards.

Comment: What does the XSL look like that you are currently using? Can you edit that into your question?

Comment: Sorry, i cannot copy my code keep due to restrictions :(

Comment: Without that your question will most likely be closed because it doesn't show any research effort. Basically, it needs to show what you tried and why it didn't work. Otherwise, any answer you get would be speculation on our part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention XSLT/XPath version you are using.

In XPath 2.0 you could do

```
string-join(//PIN, ', ')
```

which produces output

```
202, 203
```

In XSLT 2.0 you could do

```
<xsl:value-of select="//PIN" separator=", " />
```

In XSLT 1.0 you could do for example

```
<xsl:for-each select="//PIN">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```